Security for guacd proxy (Apache Guacamole)
Since the Apache Guacamole documentation, it is said in the Docker installation of guacd that leveraging its port to the host (with "docker run --name some-guacd -d -p 4822:4822 guacamole/guacd") would be a potential security issue.
My question is: isn't it the same if the daemon is installed without Docker, natively, on the same server?
My aim is to get an Apache Guacamole service that could deal with the RDP of machines that are not on docker (just on the same network as the host [either via docker or natively])

Well not really the same, let's say you are behind a router(DHCP) and your IP is 192.168.0.100, I will give you both implementations:

Docker - You have two containers(guacd and the tomcat for guacamole UI), in this case only the tomcat container is exposed with a port(e.g. 8080), the frontend make requests to backend(guacd) and they communicate with each other via docker proxy daemon. In the same docker network.
Host - Almost the same method, but here guacd listens on 127.0.0.1(localhost) which can only be accessed inside the host and only tomcat listens to 192.168.0.100 so it can be accessed from other hosts in the same network.

The main difference between the two implementations is that in the first docker proxy daemon is placed between the services and the host.
Here is a quick example:
prepare.sh
#!/bin/sh
# check if docker is running
if ! (sudo docker ps >/dev/null 2>&1)
then
        echo "docker daemon not running, will exit"
        exit
fi
echo "Preparing folder init and creating ./init/initdb.sql"
mkdir ./init >/dev/null 2>&1
mkdir ./guac_home >/dev/null 2>&1
chmod -R +x ./init
sudo docker run --rm guacamole/guacamole /opt/guacamole/bin/initdb.sh --postgresql > ./init/initdb.sql
echo "done"

docker-compose.yml
networks:
  guacnetwork:
    driver: bridge

services:
  guacd:
    container_name: guacd
    image: guacamole/guacd
    networks:
      guacnetwork:
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
    - ./drive:/drive:rw
    - ./record:/record:rw

  postgres:
    container_name: postgres_guacamole
    environment:
      PGDATA: /var/lib/postgresql/data/guacamole
      POSTGRES_DB: guacamole_db
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 'PASSWORD'
      POSTGRES_USER: guacamole_user
    image: postgres
    networks:
      guacnetwork:
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
    - ./init:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d:z
    - ./data:/var/lib/postgresql/data:Z

  guacamole:
    container_name: guacamole
    depends_on:
    - guacd
    - postgres
    environment:
      GUACD_HOSTNAME: guacd
      POSTGRES_DATABASE: guacamole_db
      POSTGRES_HOSTNAME: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 'PASSWORD'
      POSTGRES_USER: guacamole_user
      REMOTE_IP_VALVE_ENABLED: true
      GUACAMOLE_HOME: /guacamole_home
    image: guacamole/guacamole
    links:
    - guacd
    networks:
      guacnetwork:
    ports:
    - 8080:8080/tcp
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
    - ./guac_home:/guacamole_home:rw


Thank you for your explanation. About the aim of reaching machines with RDP via guacd, I'm not sure it's clear for me... My comprehension is that Tomcat is for the Guacamole client (users would use it to access machines on the web interface), and guacd deals with other machines' protocols to serve the access. If guacd is only on docker network, it could not reach machines that are not in this network, right? So for this, would I be compelled to use the "native" way of installation (without docker), to access these other machines (with RDP)? Thanks a lot

No, you should be able to reach any host which is also reachable from the host where docker lives. The way docker works is that it creates a virtual adapter for every container and gives it a 172.x.x.x IP in most cases, but the docker daemon itself will route the traffic to the corresponding physical adapters on the host. You can run guacamole UI and guacd in docker and it should work the same way as it is installed locally. I have an example docker compose file, I can share it here if you want to?

Thank you Zhivko, I understand better. So I may not have to leverage the port for guacd! That's good news. It'd be very nice for the docker compose file, it could be a good starting reference for setting up the solution

Added the code to my answer, first execute the prepare.sh script to fetch the database script and I would recommend you to bind the postgres image to a specific version, because major version upgrades brake the database, ex.: image: postgres:17

Thank you a lot for your help!
